# Java8 stream groupingBy enum and counting

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

With the classes:

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private Color favouriteColor;
}

public enum Color {GREEN, YELLOW, BLUE, RED, ORANGE, PURPLE}
```

Having a `List<Person>` using the Java8 Stream API can I trasform it in a `Map<Color, Long>` having the count of each `Color`, also for the color that aren't included in the list.
Example:

```
List<Person> list = List.of(
    new Person("Karl", Color.RED),
    new Person("Greg", Color.BLUE),
    new Person("Andrew", Color.GREEN)
);
```

Trasforming this list in a Map with **all** the colors of the enum with their count.

Thanks

SOLVED

Solved using a custom collector:

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> Collector<T, ?, Map<T, Long>> counting(Class<T> type) {
    return Collectors.toMap(
        Function.<T>identity(),
        x -> 1l,
        Long::sum,
        () -> new HashMap(Stream.of(type.getEnumConstants()).collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.<T>identity(),t -> 0l)))
    );
}


list.stream()
    .map(Person::getFavouriteColor)
    .collect(counting(Color.class))
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `groupingBy` collector to create a map but if you want to add default values for absent keys, you have to ensure that the returned map is mutable by providing a `Supplier` for the map. On the other hand, this adds the opportunity to create an `EnumMap` which is more suitable to this use case:

```
EnumMap<Color, Long> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    Person::getFavouriteColor, ()->new EnumMap<>(Color.class), Collectors.counting()));
EnumSet.allOf(Color.class).forEach(c->map.putIfAbsent(c, 0L));
```

May be, you think it’s cleaner to fill the map with default values within the supplier function:

```
EnumMap<Color, Long> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Person::getFavouriteColor, x->1L, Long::sum, ()->{
        EnumMap<Color, Long> em = new EnumMap<>(Color.class);
        EnumSet.allOf(Color.class).forEach(c->em.put(c, 0L));
        return em;
    }));
```

but of course, you can also use a stream to create that initial map:

```
EnumMap<Color, Long> map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Person::getFavouriteColor, x->1L, Long::sum, () ->
        EnumSet.allOf(Color.class).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        x->x, x->0L, Long::sum, ()->new EnumMap<>(Color.class)))));
```

But for completeness, you can do the same without the stream API, if you wish:

```
EnumMap<Color, Long> map = new EnumMap<>(Color.class);
list.forEach(p->map.merge(p.getFavouriteColor(), 1L, Long::sum));
EnumSet.allOf(Color.class).forEach(c->map.putIfAbsent(c, 0L));
```

Comment: Thanks, I found a way to generalize your solution for all enum types.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with:

```
Map<Color, Long> counted = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getFavouriteColor(), 
                                       Collectors.counting()));
```

Of course, this implies that you have a getter for the `Person#favouriteColor` member.

Then, in order to add the non-existing `Color`s to the Map, you can stream over all `Color` values, filter those who are not used as keys for the Map yet and put them with value of `0`:

```
Stream.of(Color.values())
      .filter(x -> !counted.containsKey(x))
      .forEach(x -> counted.put(x, 0L));
```

Comment: You can use `Arrays.asList(Color.values()).forEach(x -> counted.putIfAbsent(x, 0L));`

Comment: It's best to not rely on Map returned by groupingBy being mutable. Javadoc says "There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Map returned."  It would be better to use the 3-argument version of `groupingBy` with  `HashMap::new` or `() -> new EnumMap<>(Color.class)` as second argument.

Comment: Depending on what you're using it for, instead of relying on mutability you can collect the counts as described above and use `counted.getOrDefault(value, 0L)` when looking them up.