# Java use streams to get amount of ordered products by month

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I would like to prepare simple report that shows number of ordered products by month like this (descending order):

```
Month         Number of products
2018-10       8
2018-11       3
```

My data:

```
  class Orders {

        private List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

        public void prepareData() {

            Product socks = new ProductBuilder()
                    .setPrice(new BigDecimal("23"))
                    .setCategory(Category.C)
                    .setName("SOCKS")
                    .build();

            Product jacket = new ProductBuilder()
                    .setPrice(new BigDecimal("199"))
                    .setCategory(Category.A)
                    .setName("JACKET")
                    .build();

            Product watch = new ProductBuilder()
                    .setPrice(new BigDecimal("100"))
                    .setCategory(Category.B)
                    .setName("WATCH CASIO")
                    .build();


            Customer john = new CustomerBuilder()
                    .setAge(18)
                    .setName("JOHN")
                    .setSurname("JOHNSON")
                    .setEmail("john@johnson.com")
                    .build();

            Customer mike = new CustomerBuilder()
                    .setAge(20)
                    .setName("MIKE")
                    .setSurname("MAX")
                    .setEmail("mike@max.com")
                    .build();


            Order orderJohn = new OrderBuilder()
                    .setQuantity(2)
                    .setCustomer(john)
                    .setProduct(watch)
                    .setOrderDate(LocalDate.now())
                    .build();

            Order orderJohn2 = new OrderBuilder()
                    .setQuantity(4)
                    .setCustomer(john)
                    .setProduct(socks)
                    .setOrderDate(LocalDate.now())
                    .build();


             Order orderMike = new OrderBuilder()
                    .setQuantity(2)
                    .setCustomer(mike)
                    .setProduct(jacket)
                    .setOrderDate(LocalDate.now())
                    .build();

            orders.add(orderJohn);
            orders.add(orderJohn2);


            orders.add(orderMike);
    }
}
```

Now, I using `groupingBy` to get number of order by month

```
System.out.println(orders.stream()
       .collect(Collectors
               .groupingBy(e -> e.getOrderDate().withDayOfMonth(1), Collectors.counting())));
```

But how to add number of products by month? `Quantity` field in `Order` class.

```
public class Order {

    private Customer customer;
    private Product product;
    private int quantity;
    private LocalDate orderDate;
   //get/set
}

public class Customer {

    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private int age;
    private String email;
    //get/set
}

public class Product {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private Category category;
    //get/set
}
```

And builders

```
public class CustomerBuilder {

    private Customer customer = new Customer();

    public CustomerBuilder setName(String name){
        customer.setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public CustomerBuilder setSurname(String surname){
        customer.setSurname(surname);
        return this;
    }

    public CustomerBuilder setAge(int age){
        customer.setAge(age);
        return this;
    }

    public CustomerBuilder setEmail(String email){
        customer.setEmail(email);
        return this;
    }

    public Customer build()  {

        return customer;
    }

}
public class OrderBuilder {
   private Order order = new Order();

   public OrderBuilder setCustomer(Customer customer){
       order.setCustomer(customer);
       return this;
   }

   public OrderBuilder setProduct(Product product){
       order.setProduct(product);
       return this;
   }

   public OrderBuilder setQuantity(int quantity){
       order.setQuantity(quantity);
       return this;
   }

   public OrderBuilder setOrderDate(LocalDate orderDate){
       order.setOrderDate(orderDate);
       return this;
   }

   public Order build(){
       return order;
   }

}

public class ProductBuilder {

    private Product product = new Product();

    public ProductBuilder setCategory(Category category){
        product.setCategory(category);
        return this;
    }

    public ProductBuilder setName(String name){
        product.setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public ProductBuilder setPrice(BigDecimal bigDecimal){
        product.setPrice(bigDecimal);
        return this;
    }

    public Product build() {
        return product;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague and have to sum up your entire question in one sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
Please post [mcve].  There is no need for so much code (and yet not executable) for the question asked.

Comment: @lukassz see my edited answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace your `Collectors.counting()` with:

```
Collectors.summingInt(Order::getQuantity)
```

(it works like that: `Collectors.reducing(0, Order::getQuantity, Integer::sum)`)

**EDIT:**

Looking at your comment on the other answer, here is what you need:

```
Map<LocalDate, IntSummaryStatistics> ord = orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getOrderDate().withDayOfMonth(1), Collectors.summarizingInt(Order::getQuantity)));
ord.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((p1,p2) -> Long.compare(p2.getSum(), p1.getSum()))).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I have another question, how to get most popular category by month?

Comment: Check one of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31537763/java8-stream-groupingby-enum-and-counting) but use it together with `Collectors.maxBy()`.

Comment: I'm trying to do in this way `orders.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(e -> e.getOrderDate().withDayOfMonth(1)))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getCategory, Collectors.counting()));` but I'm gets error

Answer (score 0):

Use `Collectors.summingInt(Order::getQuantity)` instead of `Collectors.counting()`.

Comment: yes I do this  `Map<LocalDate, IntSummaryStatistics> ord = orders.stream()
               .collect(Collectors
                       .groupingBy(e -> e.getOrderDate().withDayOfMonth(1),
                               Collectors.summarizingInt(Order::getQuantity)));
       ord.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingLong(p -> p.getValue().getSum()));` but how to reverse order?