# Conditions for a List with Java8 with Consumer or Filter, which way is better

Tags: java, foreach, java-8, java-stream, consumer

I have tried this

```
    List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 0, -1, -1);
    List<Integer> positiveNum2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> negativeNum2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> zeroNumbers2 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> positiveNumbers = numbers.stream().filter(number -> number > 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> negativeNumbers = numbers.stream().filter(number -> number < 0).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Integer> zeroNumbers = numbers.stream().filter(number -> number.equals(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    positiveNumbers.forEach(System.out::println);
    negativeNumbers.forEach(System.out::println);
    zeroNumbers.forEach(System.out::println);
    System.out.println("*********with Consumer******************");
    Consumer<Integer> determineNumber = number -> {
        if (number > 0) {
            positiveNum2.add(number);
        } else if (number < 0) {
            negativeNum2.add(number);
        } else {
            zeroNumbers2.add(number);
        }

    };
    numbers.forEach(determineNumber);
    positiveNum2.forEach(System.out::println);
    negativeNum2.forEach(System.out::println);
    zeroNumbers2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

but I dont know which one is better, I think the forEach with the Consumer, but the Consumer does three validations, therefore, does not have single responsability

Comment: It does have a single responsibility, i.e. dividing the numbers over three lists based on their sign. The consumer only takes one iteration, so is more efficient. I'd just use a simple `for` loop for this though...

Comment: I agree on simple `for` loop for this. --- I'm curious: Why `number.equals(0)` and not `number == 0`?

Comment: @Andress because `==` is used to check the reference of the object, not the value. while `equals` used to `compare` the value of the object. here numbers is the `List` of `Integer class`  that is why `equals` is used here.

Comment: @DhrumilPatel I think you'll find `==` is perfectly fine here.  And talking about "the reference of the object" is a very confusing way of explaining what `==` actually does.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thank you for the giving of your review on my comment. I just want to say that `==` is used for `reference comparison(Address Comparison)` of the object. and `equals()` is used for `content comparison`. and here numbers is `List` of `Integer class` that is why `equals()` is used here.

Comment: @DhrumilPatel That doesn't apply here.  When you compare an `Integer` to an `int` using `==`, the `Integer` gets unboxed, and you get a value comparison.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes you are right `Integer(wrapper class)` will `unbox` to `int(Primitive)` if we compare Integer and int using `==`. but it will fail if `Integer(wrapper class)` is compared with `Integer(wrapper class)`

Comment: @DhrumilPatel That's not necessarily true either. `Integer`s have a pool as well. Comparing 2 `Integers` with `==` will produce the same results as comparing with `equals`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700081/why-is-128-128-false-but-127-127-is-true-when-comparing-integer-wrappers-in-ja?lq=1).

Comment: @sweeper yes but it will be true for the range of -128 to 127 but not for greater than that. please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149959/using-operator-in-java-to-compare-wrapper-objects).

Comment: @DhrumilPatel Yep, that's what I meant. I forgot to say -128 to 127.

Comment: @Sweeper it's not true that `==` and `equals` always return the same result for `Integer` objects with values between -128 and 127. The fact that there is a pool of objects available doesn't imply that every object in that range was taken from the pool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The consumer only takes one iteration, so it's more efficient, and it *does* have a single responsibility: dividing the numbers over three lists based on their sign.

For this case, I'd probably use a simple `for` loop though.

If you really want to over-engineer things, you can define an `enum` to represent the sign, and use a grouping collector to group into a map:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 1, 0, -1, -1);

        Map<Sign, List<Integer>> map = numbers
                .stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(i -> i > 0
                                    ? Sign.POSITIVE
                                    : i < 0 
                                        ? Sign.NEGATIVE
                                        : Sign.ZERO));

        System.out.println(map);
    }
}

enum Sign {POSITIVE, NEGATIVE, ZERO}
```

This yields the following output:

```
{ZERO=[0], POSITIVE=[1, 1], NEGATIVE=[-1, -1]}
```

---

<sup>**Note:** If you want peak performance for future lookups in your map, you can use an `EnumMap` instead. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31540398/3558960) to see how.</sup>

Comment: Pretty nice, i will try, can you tell where can I learn more about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would generally prefer your `Consumer` based solution as it at least encapsulates the whole operation in one call/stream. But I think you don't yet take full advantage of the functional approach of streams.

You could use a simple stream/collect to achieve this sorting:

```
numbers .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Math::signum));
```

will result in a map like this:

```
{1.0=[1], 0.0=[0, 0], -1.0=[-1, -2, -1]}
```

This approach avoids side effects (i.e. does not modify lists outside of the stream's scope) and can hence be extracted more easily and is easily run in parallel.

Comment: Pretty nice, I did not know about this Collectors, thanks a lot